# Swift alert view with OK and Cancel: which button tapped?

Tags: xcode, dialog, swift, alert, confirmation

I have an alert view in Xcode written in Swift and I'd like to determine which button the user selected (it is a confirmation dialog) to do nothing or to execute something.

Currently I have:

```
@IBAction func pushedRefresh(sender: AnyObject) {
    var refreshAlert = UIAlertView()
    refreshAlert.title = "Refresh?"
    refreshAlert.message = "All data will be lost."
    refreshAlert.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
    refreshAlert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
    refreshAlert.show()
}
```

I'm probably using the buttons wrong, please do correct me since this is all new for me.

Comment: duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195310/how-to-add-an-action-to-a-uialertview-button-using-swift-ios

Answer (score 358, accepted):

If you are using iOS8, you should be using UIAlertController — UIAlertView is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/).

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
var refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Refresh", message: "All data will be lost.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
  print("Handle Ok logic here")
  }))

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
  print("Handle Cancel Logic here")
  }))

presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

As you can see the block handlers for the UIAlertAction handle the button presses.  A great tutorial is here (although this tutorial is not written using swift):
http://hayageek.com/uialertcontroller-example-ios/

**Swift 3 update:**

```
let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Refresh", message: "All data will be lost.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    print("Handle Ok logic here")
}))

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    print("Handle Cancel Logic here")
}))

present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Swift 5 update:**

```
let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Refresh", message: "All data will be lost.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
      print("Handle Ok logic here")
}))

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
      print("Handle Cancel Logic here")
}))

present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Swift 5.3 update:**

```
let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Refresh", message: "All data will be lost.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
      print("Handle Ok logic here")
}))

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
      print("Handle Cancel Logic here")
}))

present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You could make use of the `UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel` rather than `.Default` in your example.

Comment: If I want to do nothing in Cancel action I can return nothing ?

Comment: Of course, technically, I am doing nothing in the example but logging.  But if I removed the log I would be doing nothing.

Comment: it's so great when answers are updated for the newer Swift versions

Comment: anyone knows how to add accessibility id to "ok" and "cancel" actions

Comment: so the difference between swift 3 and swift 5 is one tab in the print line? xD

Answer (score 25):

```
var refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Log Out", message: "Are You Sure to Log Out ? ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}))

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

    refreshAlert .dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


}))

presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Update Swift 5.3:                                                               
refreshAlert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do this by using UIAlertController

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(
       title: "Your title", message: "Your message", preferredStyle: .alert)
let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(
       title: "Close Alert", style: .default, handler: nil)
//you can add custom actions as well 
alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

.

Reference: [iOS Show Alert](https://www.simplifiedios.net/ios-show-alert-using-uialertcontroller/)

Answer (score 4):

> Updated for swift 3:

// function defination:

```
@IBAction func showAlertDialog(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Declare Alert
        let dialogMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Confirm", message: "Are you sure you want to Logout?", preferredStyle: .alert)

        // Create OK button with action handler
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
             print("Ok button click...")
             self.logoutFun()
        })

        // Create Cancel button with action handlder
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) -> Void in
            print("Cancel button click...")
        }

        //Add OK and Cancel button to dialog message
        dialogMessage.addAction(ok)
        dialogMessage.addAction(cancel)

        // Present dialog message to user
        self.present(dialogMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

// logoutFun() function definaiton :

```
func logoutFun()
{
    print("Logout Successfully...!")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Hit Upvote :)**

**Step # 1:  Make a new Separate Class**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

        class AppAlert: NSObject {
        
        //Singleton class
        static let shared = AppAlert()
        
        //MARK: - Delegate
        var onTapAction : ((Int)->Void)?
        
        //Simple Alert view
        public func simpleAlert(view: UIViewController, title: String?, message: String?){
            ToastManager.show(title: title ?? "", state: .error)
        }
        
        //Alert view with Single Button
        public func simpleAlert(view: UIViewController, title: String, message: String, buttonTitle: String) {
            
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            //okButton Action
            let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle, style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) {
                (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                self.onTapAction?(0)
            }
            alert.addAction(okButton)
            view.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
        //Alert view with Two Buttons
        public func simpleAlert(view: UIViewController, title: String, message: String, buttonOneTitle: String, buttonTwoTitle: String){
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            
            //Button One Action
            let buttonOne = UIAlertAction(title: buttonOneTitle, style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) {
                (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                self.onTapAction?(0)
            }
            
            //Button Two Action
            let buttonTwo = UIAlertAction(title: buttonTwoTitle, style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) {
                (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                self.onTapAction?(1)
            }
            alert.addAction(buttonOne)
            alert.addAction(buttonTwo)
            view.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
    }
```

> Step # 2: Call As

```
    AppAlert.shared.simpleAlert(view: self, title: "Register First", message: "Please Register to Proceed", buttonOneTitle: "Cancel", buttonTwoTitle: "OK")
            AppAlert.shared.onTapAction = { [weak self] tag in
                guard let self = self else {
                    return
                }
                if tag == 0 {
                  // DO YOUR WORK  
                } else if tag == 1 {
                 // DO YOUR WORK  
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is ToastManager here ?

Comment: You can mange your business logic here I had show custom alert with toastmanager class

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using **SCLAlertView**, alternative for **UIAlertView** or **UIAlertController**.

UIAlertController only works on iOS 8.x or above, SCLAlertView is a good option to support older version.

[github](https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift/blob/master/README.md) to see the details

example:

```
let alertView = SCLAlertView()
alertView.addButton("First Button", target:self, selector:Selector("firstButton"))
alertView.addButton("Second Button") {
    print("Second button tapped")
}
alertView.showSuccess("Button View", subTitle: "This alert view has buttons")
```

Answer (score -1):

small update for swift 5:

```
let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Refresh", message: "All data will be lost.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

    refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
          print("Handle Ok logic here")
    }))

    refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
          print("Handle Cancel Logic here")
    }))

    self.present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```