# how can I implement a "delete" notification in swift

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

How do I implement a delete notification in swift? So if I have a delete button the "are you sure" notification box pops up with delete and cancel options, I thought it would be in the info.plist but haven't seen anything, can anyone help?

Comment: nothing I yet, I know how to do the delete implementation but i just have no clue how to get the notification to pop up once the button is pressed

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. You need to explain better. I gather you have defined a push notification that tells you app to delete something? And you want to display a message to the user asking them to confirm the delete action? If so, what part of the problem are you having trouble with?

Comment: sorry for being unclear, i want a notification that pops up when a delete button is pressed, one of apples standard ones that says "are you sure you want to delete" with the 2 options "delete" and "cancel", i have no idea how to set up the notification. hope that is more clear

Comment: Are you sure you want a notification? Don't you want some kind of modal dialog? Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25511945/swift-alert-view-ios8-with-ok-and-cancel-button-which-button-tapped

Comment: yes thats exactly what i want, i didn't know what those were called  thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its easy Just link your button to you code using an `IBAction` then in the function write the alert code.

So your code should like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func showAlertButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // create the alert
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "UIAlertController", message: "Would you like to continue learning how to use iOS alerts?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        // add the actions (buttons)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: 

UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))

            // show the alert
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift 4

```
    @IBAction func DeleteButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let DeleteAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Request will be deleted", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        DeleteAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            //Add your Action for deleting
        }))

        DeleteAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            //if anything to do after cancel clicked
        }))
        present(DeleteAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```