# 'UIAlertView' was deprecated in iOS 9.0. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I have see more so answers , but nothing helped.Here is my older alert and action for that

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
        print("internet connection ok")
    } else 
    {
        print("internet not ok")
        let alertView: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Alert ", message: "connect to internet", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "settings", otherButtonTitles: "cancel")
        alertView.show()
        return       
    }       
}

func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int)
{
    if buttonIndex == 0 {
        //This will open ios devices wifi settings
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "prefs:root")!)
    }
    else if buttonIndex == 1
    {
        //TODO for cancel
        exit(0) 
    }
}
```

In that i am getting warning :

> 'UIAlertView' was deprecated in iOS 9.0. Use UIAlertController with a
>   preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead

I tried :

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "My Alert for test", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {    (action:UIAlertAction!) in 
        print("you have pressed the Cancel button")
    }))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But to add two button and add the index path of button press method link my older code,I am not able to do that. Nothing action happening fro my uialert button,

Please help me out,How can i remove that warnings and recode my Uialert with my two button action.

I am new to swift.Your help will be useful.Thanks!

Comment: Why you need button index in above case ? Write the code that need to be executed for each of those button click in it's handler block/closure.

Comment: @user5513630 if we use UIAlertCOntroller instead of UIAlertView , then can we use  this function  "func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){} " if not then what is the alternative? please help me , i am new

Comment: @MidhunMP if we use UIAlertCOntroller instead of UIAlertView , then can we use  this function  "func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){} " if not then what is the alternative? please help me , i am new

Comment: @ArgaPK: You can't use that method. For each button there is a closure block (Refer UIAlertAction), when that button is clicked corresponding closure will be executed. Check the following answers to get a clear idea

Comment: @MidhunMP Thank You

Answer (score 73, accepted):

See this Code Destructive and OK buttons in `UIAlertController`:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Destructive", message: "Simple alertView demo with Destructive and Ok.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert) //Replace UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert by UIAlertControllerStyle.alert
let DestructiveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Destructive", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive) {
    (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    print("Destructive")
}

// Replace UIAlertActionStyle.Default by UIAlertActionStyle.default
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
    (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    print("OK")
}

alertController.addAction(DestructiveAction)
alertController.addAction(okAction)
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Swift 3:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Destructive", message: "Simple alertView demo with Destructive and Ok.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert) //Replace UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert by UIAlertControllerStyle.alert

let DestructiveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Destructive", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive) {
                        (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    print("Destructive")
}

                    // Replace UIAlertActionStyle.Default by UIAlertActionStyle.default

let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
                        (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    print("OK")
}

alertController.addAction(DestructiveAction)
alertController.addAction(okAction)
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**See Alert With Destructive and OK Button:**

[image]

Comment: what about action method?? does i need to mention seperate method for that??

Comment: No Not.This is new in AlertController. And Button action event handle in this method.

Comment: for example when i press ok button i need to use this line `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "prefs:root")!)` then where i can add this line in your code

Comment: instead of that `print("ok"), i need to add this line...Rignt??

Comment: @KiritModi if we use UIAlertCOntroller instead of UIAlertView , then can we use  this function  "func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){} " if not then what is the alternative? please help me , i am new

Comment: @ArgaPK in the UIAlertCOntroller there are individual method of Buttons. So do the code in this button. you can see the OK button of above code.

Comment: @KiritModi you mean there is nothing like func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex bi: Int){} ?? if yes then how we write method? using UIAertAction?? Can we write this "   if buttonIndex == 0 {
        //This will open ios devices wifi settings
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "prefs:root")!)
    }
    else if buttonIndex == 1
    {
        //TODO for cancel
        exit(0) 
    } " in UIALertAction of Button OK??

Comment: Remove the code and add code like:


let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
                        (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "prefs:root")!)
    print("OK")
}

Comment: @KiritModi ok let me try

Comment: @KiritModi what does it mean " UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "prefs:root")!) " ? what will happen with this line of code?

Comment: it's your reference so I added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157973/discussion-between-argapk-and-kirit-modi).

Answer (score 15):

In **Swift 3**, you can write this:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "This is my text", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)  
{ 
     (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
      print("You pressed OK")
}
alertController.addAction(okAction)
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 11):

For a basic alert message I like using an extension on UIViewController:

```
extension UIViewController {
func alertMessageOk(title: String, message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

Usage: 
`self.alertMessageOk(title: "Test Title", message: "Test message")`

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

```
    // Create message
     let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title",
                                           message: "Message",
                                    preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    // Clear Action
    let clearAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Clear",
                                    style: .destructive,
                                  handler: { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
                         print ("clear")
    })
    alertController.addAction(clearAction)

    // Cancel
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
                                     style: .cancel,
                                   handler: { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
                                print ("Cancel")
    })
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    // Present Alert
    self.present(alertController,
                 animated: true,
                 completion:nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  UIAlertController *AC = UIAlertController.alertControllerWithTitle("Title",message:"Message",preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert)

  UIAlertAction *ActionOne = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:"ActionOne" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) { NSLog("ActionOne")
} ]

  UIAlertAction *ActionTwo = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:"ActionTwo" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) { NSLog("ActionTwo")
} ]
AC.addAction(ActionOne)
AC.addAction(ActionTwo)
self.presentViewController(AC,animated:true,completion:nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
Ex

```
 let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure?", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)
 let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "NO", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
                 //Do your task
  }
  actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)
  let nextAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "YES", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
           //Do your task             //NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removePersistentDomainForName(NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier!)
      //                  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
 }
 actionSheetController.addAction(nextAction)
 self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: if we use UIAlertCOntroller instead of UIAlertView , then can we use  this function  "func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){} " if not then what is the alternative? please help me , i am new

Comment: @ArgaPK can you try Handler alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay",
                          style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                        handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in println("Your code")}))

Answer (score 0):

This code will help

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Default AlertController", message: "A standard alert", preferredStyle: .Alert)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) 
{ 
   (action:UIAlertAction!) in
   print("you have pressed the Cancel button");
}
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) 
{ 
  (action:UIAlertAction!) in
                print("you have pressed OK button");
}
alertController.addAction(OKAction)

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: because i have set button click = 0,1 means i have set some action there know. so only asked

Comment: NO,you need to call your action method where i m printing (EX."you have pressed the Cancel button") when button pressed. You need to modify this code.

Comment: Just replace that print statement to your method call.SIMPLE

Comment: yes, i replace my action method call,Like `alertView` with the replacement of that print statement.But no action occur. does i am right to call that action method ??

Comment: You are using old action's delegate method (and that method's parameters will be nil) so make new custom method with new name and then try to call it .It will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

I have get this answer from this link i think it is useful to you

[How to add an action to a UIAlertView button using Swift iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195310/how-to-add-an-action-to-a-uialertview-button-using-swift-ios)

```
    var alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)

// Create the actions
var okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
    UIAlertAction in
    NSLog("OK Pressed")
}
var cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) {
    UIAlertAction in
    NSLog("Cancel Pressed")
}

// Add the actions
alertController.addAction(okAction)
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

// Present the controller
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```