# create a new UIAlert based on a previous UIAlert's button click

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make an app where you can click to book a reservation. When you click on the button of the reservation you want, an UIAlert will show up and ask if you want to confirm the action. If so, then another UIAlert will show up and confirm your reservation.

I'm having difficulties to understand how to make this series os UIAlerts. Here's the code.

```
 @IBAction func garageinn(_ sender: Any) {

    var refreshAlert = UIAlertView()
    refreshAlert.title = "Book a vacancy?"
    refreshAlert.message = "A vacancy will be reserved at Garage Inn."
    refreshAlert.addButton(withTitle: "Cancel")
    refreshAlert.addButton(withTitle: "Ok")
    refreshAlert.show()
}
```

Comment: Use `UIAlertController` instead of `UIAlertView` if you are targeting iOS 8.0 or later.

Comment: You should probably be using [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller) because UIAlertView is deprecated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an action to a UIAlertView button using Swift iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195310/how-to-add-an-action-to-a-uialertview-button-using-swift-ios)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, it was really a duplicate of the one you showed up here. Updated to UIAlertController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use UIAlertController as stated for some in the comments.

```
let alert : UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
```

And add an actions (buttons) as required

```
let accept : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Accept", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
    // -code to process- and -create new alert-
})

let cancel : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
```

As shown you must create the code to process the response in the handler, including creating the new alert.

Comment: Good to know, Please select as the answer ;)